# Getting the image in a PictureBox control with the lines drawn using a graphics object

Tags: c#, image

I have troubles understanding how the graphics objects are drawn. Suppose to have this function:

```
private void DrawLineOnOverlay()
{
        using (var g = pictureBox.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.DrawLine(OverlayPen, cursorStartx, cursorStarty, cursorEndx, cursorEndy);
        }         
}
```

to draw simple lines in a pictureBox control where you have *already* done this:

```
pictureBox.Image = BitmapToBeLoaded;    // Load an 8-bit indexed Bitmap
```

My understanding is that both the image loaded and the pixel drawn using the graphics object are parte of the very same image: pictureBox.Image

but this:

```
Bitmap graphic = pictureBox.Image;
if (graphic  != null )  
{               
    graphic = new Bitmap (pictureBox.Image);       
    graphic.Save( "C:\\packed.png", ImageFormat.Png);       
}
```

does not work: the image saved does not show the lines drawn in red over the image. Why this? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to save your drawings then you need to draw them on a surface and then save the surface. Usually, drawing on `PictureBox` canvas would not let you save the image because the `Image` class has nothing to do with drawings. `Image` is just an abstract class on top of `Bitmap` which is able to load a GDI+ supported image file and then present it in `PictureBox`. Drawings are done on a GDI+ drawing surface which is `Graphics` object.

You can create a surface:

```
Bitmap surface = new Bitmap(640, 480);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(surface);

using (var OverlayPen = new Pen(Color.Red))
{
  g.DrawLine(OverlayPen, cursorStartx, cursorStarty, cursorEndx, cursorEndy);
}
```

If you want to show drawings, you can set `Surface` as `PictureBox`'s image. And remember to use `using` pattern when you are creating graphical objects like pens or brushes because if you don't they're going to stay on memory all the way to the end of the context and they may cause overflow at some points.

To save then:

```
surface.Save( "C:\\packed.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```